# Angular application does not refresh content on change despite rebuilding

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've started a project with ASP.Net core Web API as a backend with Angular app on the front. However, instead of using the default template for SPA for Angular I've decided to do it on my own. So I've created a blank ASP.NET Core project, then added Angular project using Angular CLI. Literally the only thing I changed in the Angular project config was the outputPath in angular.json - I changed it to ../wwwroot.

Then i set up everything in .Net application in Startup class.

I start the angular with `ng serve`, then build the .net project using Visual Studio. However the Angular app does not refresh/change content when it detects changes in one of its files. Interestingly it does some rebuilding, but the new content would not appear unless i stop the app, run `ng build` and then start it again with `ng serve`. I believe I messed up the configuration in either project, so any help would be appreciated. I've provided some code below

Here is my Startup class (I've hidden all the stuff related to DI or authorization setup, since I find it irrelevant)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        //Setting up DbContext, DI and authorization

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(spa =>
        {
            spa.RootPath = "wwwroot";
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "client-app";
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my angular.json

```
    {
        "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
        "version": 1,
        "newProjectRoot": "projects",
        "projects": {
            "client-app": {
                "projectType": "application",
                "schematics": {},
                "root": "",
                "sourceRoot": "src",
                "prefix": "app",
                "architect": {
                    "build": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                        "options": {
                            "outputPath": "../wwwroot",
                            "index": "src/index.html",
                            "main": "src/main.ts",
                            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "aot": false,
                            "assets": [
                                "src/favicon.ico",
                                "src/assets"
                            ],
                            "styles": [
                                "src/styles.css"
                            ],
                            "scripts": []
                        },
                        "configurations": {
                            "production": {
                                "fileReplacements": [
                                    {
                                        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "optimization": true,
                                "outputHashing": "all",
                                "sourceMap": false,
                                "extractCss": true,
                                "namedChunks": false,
                                "aot": true,
                                "extractLicenses": true,
                                "vendorChunk": false,
                                "buildOptimizer": true,
                                "budgets": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "initial",
                                        "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                        "maximumError": "5mb"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                        "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                        "maximumError": "10kb"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "serve": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                        "options": {
                            "browserTarget": "client-app:build"
                        },
                        "configurations": {
                            "production": {
                                "browserTarget": "client-app:build:production"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "extract-i18n": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                        "options": {
                            "browserTarget": "client-app:build"
                        }
                    },
                    "test": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                        "options": {
                            "main": "src/test.ts",
                            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                            "assets": [
                                "src/favicon.ico",
                                "src/assets"
                            ],
                            "styles": [
                                "src/styles.css"
                            ],
                            "scripts": []
                        }
                    },
                    "lint": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                        "options": {
                            "tsConfig": [
                                "tsconfig.app.json",
                                "tsconfig.spec.json",
                                "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                            ],
                            "exclude": [
                                "**/node_modules/**"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "e2e": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                        "options": {
                            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                            "devServerTarget": "client-app:serve"
                        },
                        "configurations": {
                            "production": {
                                "devServerTarget": "client-app:serve:production"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "defaultProject": "client-app"
    }
```

Comment: you are telling Angular to output the build in wwwroot but when you do serve it actually has its own server and its own location.

Comment: So what should I do in order not to rebuild on every change? I'd like to automate that process for backend as well, but I've heard about dotnet watch and hope that installing that would not cause any major problems

Comment: ng build --watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on a different server not the webpack dev server thats included, you need to build and put the output in your own server wwwroot. It might be tedious but the best option is to have is `--watch` flag on your build while you are developing

try this for your local development.

```
ng build --watch
```

> Answer outdated: doesn't work with VS2019 and angular v9+

Comment: It worked, thank you. Now I'm wondering how all this is set up in the Visual Studio template, so you don't have to worry about all that stuff.

Comment: in package.json replace script start from `ng serve` to `ng build --watch` and to start use `npm start`

Comment: Nice shorthand. BTW, is it possible to enable Hot Module Replacement with the current configuration I have?

Comment: does not work with VS2019 and angular 9...the page does not refresh

Comment: I am not involved with ASP.net anymore. I have marked the answer outdated. You can put some bounty on this to attract answers or ask a new question. Sorry :(